# logger.debug("asdasdasd") can't be executed with JRebel debug

Tags: logging, intellij-idea, jrebel

When I run a springboot application with JRebel debug. The code `logger.debug(....)` can't be executed, intellij idea prompts that

```
No executable code found at line 32 in class cn.com.XXX.
```

I've found that not only logger.debug can't be executed, but other code also had this problem.

However，when I use debug without JRebel,the code will be executed,and the application work well.

**use jrebel debug：**

[image]

[image]
[image]

**use normal debug without JRebel：**

[image]
[image]

**version:**

1. springboot version：1.5.3.RELEASE
2. intellij idea version: 2017.2.6
3. jrebel version : jrebel agent 7.1.2

Comment: Please describe "can't work" more in-depth. What's the actual issue with it?

Comment: I rewrote the questions I submitted earlier.

Comment: I tried to replicate the issue on my machine but didn't succeed. Could you please reproduce this issue and send the `jrebel.log` file from `~/.jrebel/` directory to support@zeroturnaround.com? Please also specify whether do you use AOP or any other bytecode instrumenting mechanisms whilst running your application. Make sure to reference this SO article in the mail as well.

Comment: I've already submitted the problem to support@zeroturnaround.com. @Tiit